# Почему vk api выдает ошибку «ReadTimeout»?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Всем привет!
Запустил элементарного бота, он отвечает в беседах и тд.. и каждый раз после запуска скрипта(бота) - через некоторое время, python выкидывает ошибку(тоесть после запуска он работает некоторое время, а потом python выдает ошибку): `ReadTimeout`

Не знаю в чем проблема.
Вот ошибка:

```
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
request.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

Спасибо)

Comment: Проблема в неидеальной интернет-связи, такое будет всегда и от этого никуда не деться, учитесь эту ошибку обрабатывать

Comment: можете ссылку дать, что-нибудь по этой теме?

Comment: Чтобы людям с похожей проблемой было бы легче ваш вопрос найти, добавьте текст ошибки в виде текста в вопрос, а не картинки. (Полезно полный traceback добавить) Если не знаете как текст скопировать, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на сервере api vk timeout больше 10-ти секунд, тогда Вам следует указывать его при каждом запросе:

```
response = requests.post('http://example.com', timeout=20)
```

Или:

```
response = requests.get('http://example.com', timeout=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в интернет-соединении. Вы можете установить увеличенное время ответа сервера, это уже описали выше. Также советовали обработать это самое исключение. Делается это посредствам блоков try: и except: Более подробно вы можете почитать об это здесь:[здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, ты где-то не закрываешь открытые соединения. Из-за этого соединения в пуле заканчиваются, новые встают в очередь и убиваются по таймауту - вот ты и получаешь такую ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка возникает из-за плохого соединения / бездействия со стороны ВК. К сожалению данную проблему можно исправить только путём игнорирования.

Я предлагаю сделать такой вариант кода (Смею предположить что вы используете LongPoll):

```
while True:
   try:
      for event in longpoll.listen():
         try:
            ...
         except:
            ...
   except Exception as error:
      print(error) # Простая заглушка
      # Здесь можно прописать логирование ошибок, но по большей части они связаны с серверами ВК.
```

У меня написано 2 Бота при помощи такой схемы, всё отлично работает, к сожалению от данной ошибки не избавиться.